# Disable only checked checkbox in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

So I have been working on a system and I can't seem to solve how to disable only the checked checkbox inside a table. I have been looking everywhere but no answer. Would you mind helping me?

For example, I have three rows in my table and whenever I check a row all three checkbox will be disabled. What I want is, I only want the checked checkbox in the row to be disabled and the other two should be enabled.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Some code would be nice. If your checkbox has a unique class you can select all checkboxes with this class e.g `$(".checkbox").find(":checked").prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze, yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an event handler to your checkboxes like this:

```js
var disable = function(event){
   $(event.target).prop("disabled", true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="disable(event)" />
<input type="checkbox" onchange="disable(event)" />
<input type="checkbox" onchange="disable(event)" />
```